# Catch disconnect event with eventmachine (ping + timeout?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comet, faye

I am using event machine with rails with faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com/) but i have a problem. I want to make a who is online module, showing all the users currently connected on my website.

I want to create a google talk like.

There is maybe a better way that Faye to do that?

I manage my connection like that :

```
Each user has his own channel like this /messages/<user_id>
```

But my question is, how can i catch a disconnect event. I read about send pings + timeout to my comet server but i don't know how to do this.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: not sure about faye, but EM has a disconnect event if I remember correctly...

Comment: I didn't find documentation about this. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Faye Monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html). You can subscribe to the `/meta/unsubscribe` or `/meta/disconnect` channels. Faye handles the checking/pinging of the clients and the timeouts.